# What terms and expressions can be used in English to show one's love to his/her girlfriend/boyfriend?

Tags: vocabulary, expressions, hypocorisms

I know in every language there are a lot of ways and cute names to address your girlfriend or your boyfriend to show you love her/him. The names can be creative for any couple. As Andy mentions these names are called terms of endearment.

These are some very ordinary I know for examples:

> Come here, **sweetheart**.
>
> Relax **baby**, we're on holiday!
>
> Look, **darling**, there's Mary.

What else can be used to address your girlfriend/boyfriend?

Comment: For the record, these "cute names" are formally called *terms of endearment*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why resort to cliché? If you really want to find a great term of endearment, create your own. Find something that the both of you share and use that. Is there a character from a novel you both love? Something you both shared a joke about? Try that.

Often the best terms of affection are inversions of insults. For example, if your special someone was eating a doughnut once and got powdered sugar on her nose, you might have called her "Sugar Nose" (in an affectionate way, of course) and shared a laugh about it. Henceforth, Sugar Nose might serve as a special bit of sweet talk only the two of you can enjoy.

Edit: You might want to make sure you use these only in private, as they can have adverse effects if spoken within earshot of other people. Sickness, nausea ... you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: +1 because I think this is a lovely idea. Also because your edit made me laugh.

Comment: +1 Very nice idea. But I like to know what other people tend to use, and also their creative terms.

Answer (score 6):

If you want are horrifyingly large list of terms of endearment, you could do worse than [try here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120119011316/http://www.yourlovecoach.co.uk/blog/terms-of-endearment/).

Two of my personal favourites are 'ma petit chou' and 'ma petit cochon' (my little cabbage/my little piglet). Partly it amuses me because, to many English, the French language is often considered to sound romantic - yet the literal translations are rather daft (but still innocent).

Comment: “Petit cochon” is somewhat dirty, but in a nice way, in the original French. Don't ever try to use the feminine form, as “petite cochonne !” means “you slut!”.

Comment: To what FX_ mentionned earlier, make sure that you use : 'mon petit chou' instead of 'ma petit chou' and 'mon petit cochon' instead of 'ma petit cochon' They are both feminine words and the usage of 'mon' in front of them makes no sense at all in French. P.S.: my main language is French :-)

Comment: And, of course, it should be 'Ma petite...'

Answer (score 4):

As they aren't already reported by others, I can report *babycakes*, and *sweet cheeks*.

Answer (score 3):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* has a list of terms that are rather standard: *darling, dear, dearest, love, beloved, sweet, angel, honey, hon, sweetie, sugar, baby, babe, pet, treasure*.

Answer (score 3):

My husband and I are fans of *Schatz* or *Schatzi* from the German language meaning "treasure"

Comment: I've never heard anyone refer to a biped by "Schatzi".  German shepherds, poodles, even the occasional cat, but never a person.  A real "pet name", as it were.

Comment: All the better, then!

Comment: As long as you don't use the word for Jewel

Comment: @Malvolio It's very normal to call your boyfriend/girlfriend/husband/wife "Schatz" or "Schatzi" here in Germany, and to be honest I have never heard someone call their pet  "Schatz." Sounds a bit awkward to me.

Comment: (a) it's a fairly common name for German-sourced pets, like German shepherds and poodles, in the US, and (b) it's pretty sad when someone responds to a two-year-old comment of mine and I'm *right here to answer*.

Answer (score 2):

You could try *pigsney*, if you were feeling especially courageous. See here... http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Pigsney

Comment: Courageous? If you use a word that starts with *pig* with your missus, you are in serious trouble.  Explaining the etymology to her whilst ducking crockery will not work too well either.

Comment: @Orbling, quite so. That's probably the reason it's marked obsolete.